# How to use relative path in AngularJS Resource

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use the relative path in $resource and it doesn't recognize. Do I need to mention anywhere about this or Am I missing any?

It works when I provide the complete path

```
$resource('/SSystems/authenticateUser', data);
```

Comment: your application server running on 80? or another port?

Comment: @FurkanBaşaran It's running on 80
@ Satpal I tried the <base href="/application_root/" /> option but it didn't work

Comment: It's my bad, it works with <base href="/application_root/" />